# How to set an image as a cursor when hovering over a link

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, cursor

I've tried this:

a:hover
{ cursor:url(customcursor.cur), default; }

and it doesnt work, maybe im doing it wrong, can someone show me how to do it?

EDIT: found the problem... it was the picture, changing file extension doesn't work **facepalm** im an idiot

Comment: show what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <a href=''>AAA</a>
```

CSS:

```
 a {
   background:gray;
   display: block;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   cursor:url(http://www.picgifs.com/smileys/smileys-and-emoticons/money/smileys-money-671353.gif), auto;
   }
```

WORKING DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jani11bolkvadze/4fx02a6p/